# GraphQL - Sorting by attribute not working

Tags: php, symfony, graphql, api-platform.com, symfony5

I am having trouble to get all records of my entity "Project", ordered by the property "name". After following the api-platform docs about [sorting](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#order-filter-sorting), I still get the unordered collection. I need to get the result with GraphQL and I am testing the api-platform self-generated query using the graphql_playground.

My Project entity looks like this:

```
#[ApiResource(
    graphql: [
        'item_query',
        'collection_query',
        'create',
        'update',
        'delete',
    ]
)]
#[ApiFilter(
    OrderFilter::class,
    properties: ['name' => 'ASC'],
    arguments: ['orderParameterName' => 'order']
)]
class Project
{

    (...)

    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    private $name;
```

The query as I am testing which returns just unordered results:

```
{
  projects(order: { name: "ASC" }) {
    name
    (...)
  }
}
```

Comment: try to clean cache manually and reload the graphql_playground

Comment: Thank you, @JuanI.MoralesPestana. Today I revisited this task and I have already tried what you said without success. Is there any other way of cleaning the cache other than erasing the content in the /cache/ folder?

Answer (score 0):

Change your Entity annotation like this:

```
#[ApiFilter(
    OrderFilter::class,
    properties: ['name'],
    arguments: ['orderParameterName' => 'order']
)]
```